# Golang: Skipping Whitespace in a file

Tags: go

In reading a file in Go I am attempting to skip all of the white spaces; however, I am having issues finding the correct method to do this. Any assistance would be appreciated

```
file, err := os.Open(filename) // For read access.
        this.file = file
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
//skip white space

  c := make([]byte, 1)

    char, err := this.file.Read(c)

    //skip white space
    for {
            //catch unintended errors
            if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
                    panic(err)
            }
            if err == io.EOF || !unicode.IsSpace(int(c)) {
                    break
            }
            //get next
            char, err := this.file.Read(c)
    }
```

I am just simply attempting to create a scanner for a file to read a single character at a time and ignore whitespace

**EDIT**

I changed a few things around to make use of bufio.Reader; however I have still fallen into issue What is the correct way to read a file character by character so that it might be compared to a specific symbol such as 'A' but also can ignore whitespace i.e unicode.isSpace(rune)

```
char, size, err := this.reader.ReadRune()
    //skip white space and comments
    for {
            //catch unintended errors
            if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
                    panic(err)
            }
            if err == io.EOF {
                    break
            }

            //skip it when their is no data or a space
            if size != 0 && char == '{' {
                    //Ignore Comments
                    //Documentation specifies no nested comments
                    for char != '}' {
                            char, size, err = this.reader.ReadRune()
                    }
            } else if !unicode.IsSpace(char) {
                    break
            }

            // Do something with the byte
            fmt.Print(char)

            //get next
            char, size, err = this.reader.ReadRune()
    }
```

Comment: You give no context as to why you want to do this. One option is to use `golang.org/x/text/transform` to filter white space from any `io.Reader` (e.g. https://play.golang.org/p/eeo0F0Bn5S)

Comment: I am just reading a attempting to create a scanner for a file reading a character at a time

Comment: There's already a much better way to read 1 byte at a time, https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, it would seem that you'd want a `continue` statement when encountering a space.

```
c := make([]byte, 100)

n, err := this.file.Read(c)

//skip white space
for {
    //catch unintended errors
    if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        ch := c[i]

        switch ch {
        case '{': // Do something
        case '}': // Do something else
        default:
            if unicode.IsSpace(int(ch)) {
                continue
            }
            // Do whatever
        }
    }

        //get next
    n, err = this.file.Read(c)
}
```

I don't know why you're reading one byte at a time, but I left it that way in case it's intentional. At the very least, I'd think you'd want to read full unicode characters instead of individual bytes.

Comment: I switched it to 1 after I started receiving errors after skimming through another article. What is the correct count. When I try the above I get the error messages bellow ./scanner.go:107: cannot convert c (type []byte) to type int
./scanner.go:107: cannot use int(c) (type int) as type rune in argument to unicode.IsSpace

Comment: @kdgwill: Sorry, I pulled the byte out in the `Println` but not the `IsSpace()`. Fixed. There is no correct count but typically I'd take bytes in batches larger than `1`. Depends on how much memory you want to use. If memory isn't a concern, you can use `ioutil.ReadFile` to get all the data at once. It's in the `"io/ioutil"` package.

Comment: Yeah I wanted prevent loading the full file into memory, generally I am attempting to read a character to determine if it is a whitespace or if it is a specific letter/symbol.

Comment: If you only care about ASCII characters, then you could do it in batches of whatever size, say 100, and have a nested loop that reads the batch. I'll update.